# android - smooth scrolling listview with data from URL

Tags: android, json, listview, android-arrayadapter, smooth-scrolling

I have several widgets in the convertView of my listview, and all the data is parsed from json. First I form arrays from respectively parsed data and then in my ArrayAdapter I work with those final arrays. But everytime I scroll the listview, the app goes to server for the respective information (as I see in logs), despite it should have already been stored in arrays. Maybe, it's one of the reasons my listView scrolling is very slow. What's the problem?

My code for ArrayAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapterSecond extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] sSecondStartTimeArray;
private final String[] sSecondEndTimeArray;
private final String[] sSecondTitleArray;
public CustomAdapterSecond(Activity context,
                     String[] sSecondStartTimeArray, String[] sSecondEndTimeArray, String[] sSecondTitleArray) {
    super(context, R.layout.relcell2, sSecondStartTimeArray);
    this.context = context;
    this.sSecondStartTimeArray = sSecondStartTimeArray;
    this.sSecondEndTimeArray = sSecondEndTimeArray;
    this.sSecondTitleArray = sSecondTitleArray;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textStartTime;
    public TextView textEndTime;
    public TextView textUpper;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String AllData2 = HTTPRequest.GetData(URL);
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.relcell2main,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textStartTime = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textStartTime);
        holder.textEndTime = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textEndTime);
        holder.textUpper = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textUpper);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.textStartTime.setText(sSecondStartTimeArray[position]);
    holder.textEndTime.setText(sSecondEndTimeArray[position]);
    holder.textUpper.setText(sSecondTitleArray[position]);

    final int chosen = position;
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int chosenP = chosen;
            if (chosenP != 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainThird.class);
                intent.putExtra("chosenItem", chosenP);
                context.startActivity(intent);                   
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

And code for my Activity where I form the arrays:

```
public class MainSecond extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listViewLeft;
ListView listViewRight;
int secondChosen=-1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainsecond);

    secondChosen = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("chosenItem");
    final String sStartDate = getIntent().getExtras().getString("startDate");
    String sEndDate = getIntent().getExtras().getString("endDate");
    final String AllData1 = HTTPRequest.GetData(URL1);

    TabHost tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("Caption1");
    tabs.addTab(spec);
    spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Caption2");
    tabs.addTab(spec);
    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);

    final String AllData2 = HTTPRequest.GetData(URL);

    TabHost tabs2 = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost2);
    tabs2.setup();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tabs2.newTabSpec("tag12");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab12);
    spec2.setIndicator(sStartDate);
    tabs2.addTab(spec2);
    if (!(sStartDate.equals(sEndDate))) {
        spec2 = tabs2.newTabSpec("tag22");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.tab22);
        spec2.setIndicator(sEndDate);
        tabs2.addTab(spec2);
        tabs2.setCurrentTab(0);
        listViewRight = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewRight);
    }

    listViewLeft = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewLeft);

    //TODO:CreateListView
    int leng = HTTPRequest.GetLength(AllData2);
    int lengLeft=0;
    for (int i=0;i<leng;i++) {
        if (HTTPRequestSecond.GetSecondStartFecha(AllData2,i).equals(sStartDate)) lengLeft++;
    }
    ArrayList<String>sSecondStartTime=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String>sSecondEndTime=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String>sSecondTitle=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j=0;j<lengLeft;j++) {
        sSecondStartTime.add(j,HTTPRequestSecond.GetSecondStartTime(AllData2,j));
        sSecondEndTime.add(j,HTTPRequestSecond.GetSecondEndTime(AllData2, j));
        sSecondTitle.add(j,HTTPRequestSecond.GetSecondTitle(AllData2, j));
    }
    String[] sSecondStartTimeArra = new String[sSecondStartTime.size()];
    sSecondStartTimeArra = sSecondStartTime.toArray(sSecondStartTimeArra);
    String[] sSecondEndTimeArra = new String[sSecondEndTime.size()];
    sSecondEndTimeArra = sSecondEndTime.toArray(sSecondEndTimeArra);
    String[] sSecondTitleArra = new String[sSecondTitle.size()];
    sSecondTitleArra = sSecondTitle.toArray(sSecondTitleArra);
    final String[] sSecondStartTimeArray = sSecondStartTimeArra;
    final String[] sSecondEndTimeArray = sSecondEndTimeArra;
    final String[] sSecondTitleArray = sSecondTitleArra;
    CustomAdapterSecond adapter2 = new
            CustomAdapterSecond(MainSecond.this,sSecondStartTimeArray,sSecondEndTimeArray,sSecondTitleArray);
    listViewLeft.setAdapter(adapter2);
}
```

I messed up at the end but I just wanted to make the arrays final (thought it would help not to use the Internet during every scrolling) so that's why it looks so dumb way :(

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter `getView()`, the first line is calling again the remote service. Comment it and try again

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // String AllData2 = HTTPRequest.GetData(URL);
...
```

Comment: It helped, thanx! But what to do if I have another listview with Strings and images (parsed from URL too) and sometimes, when I run that Activity and scroll it right after running (without waiting several seconds), it starts to create the listview from the beginning of the arrays starting with firstly invisible items? For example, if I have 4 listView items and 3 of them are visible on the start screen, if I scroll it at once the 4th looks as the 1st. What to do?

Comment: @JustinMcGuire Normally what I do is for any `RecyclerView`/ `ListVIew` I have 3 mandatory cell layout which I use for different cases on top of any regular cells: 1) `loading_cell.xml` - showing some loading state while data update is in progress 2) `empty_cell.xml` - show when new data is null or empty, i.e. nothing to show 3) `error_cell.xml` - when new data is an error. While you download data, show (1), when data is ready, create new adapter with new data and then set it as `ListView.setAdapter()`. `Note` **Never** add heavy remote calls in `getView()` or only when absolutely necessary.